# Camel saxon Xquery : Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace

Tags: apache-camel, xquery, saxon

I'm having a big problem that I can not understand.

i have a camel route that has a xquery transformation:

```
 <transform> 
        <xquery>resource:file {{choregraphies.resources.directory}}/LINCASA1/xquery/getTypApr_request.xquery
    </xquery>
    </transform>
```

I put you inside the getTypApr_request.xquery file

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare namespace xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare namespace com="com.edfgdf.a21.business.impl";
declare variable $in.headers.prmId as xs:string external;
declare variable $in.headers.id as xs:string external;

<com:getTypApr>
<idClient>{$in.headers.id}</idClient>
<reference>{$in.headers.prmId}</reference>
</com:getTypApr>
```

Before, I was in camel 2.17 and Saxon 9.5.1-5, it works very well. I recently switched to Camel 2.21 and Saxon 9.8.0-8.
And now I see that I have an XqueryExpression in null. Camel returns to me:
 [Transform [XQuery xquery {[null]}]

I do not know what to do, could you help me

Thx

EDIT :

after research, my route starts with:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
```

Before, Xbuilder did'nt take into account the namespace of the road and now if, therefore, I have the error:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeExpressionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace
    at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:154) ~[camel-saxon-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:119) ~[camel-saxon-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.TransformProcessor.process(TransformProcessor.java:50) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:210) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:155) [camel-core-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace
    at net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.declareNamespace(StaticQueryContext.java:719) ~[Saxon-HE-9.8.0-8.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.initialize(XQueryBuilder.java:720) ~[camel-saxon-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluateAsDOM(XQueryBuilder.java:183) ~[camel-saxon-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:144) ~[camel-saxon-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is reported by Saxon when Apache camel attempts to declare a namespace binding in which either (a) the prefix is "xmlns", or (b) the namespace URI is "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/".

I have checked the 9.5 and 9.8 source code for the method StaticQueryContext.declareNamespace() and they appear to be identical: both report this error if this prefix or URI appears. So it doesn't appear to be a Saxon change that has caused the problem.

The prefix xmlns is used in declarations such as `xmlns:p="my.uri"`. In DOM, such declarations are treated as attributes whose name has (prefix=xmlns, local-name=p, uri="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"). By contrast, in the XDM data model used by XQuery, this declaration is not considered to be an attribute node; it is a namespace node with name "p" and string value "my.uri", and there is never any namespace binding for the prefix "xmlns" or the URI "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/". Section 4.13 of the XQuery 3.1 specification explicitly disallows this prefix or URI being used in a namespace declaration appearing in a query, which is why Saxon is throwing an error when StaticQueryContext.declareNamespace() is used with these values.

I've taken a look at the Camel source code at https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-saxon/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xquery/XQueryBuilder.java 
and it seems plausible that Camel is declaring every namespace binding that it encounters in a DOM, but I would need a much deeper understanding of Camel to see exactly what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

I actually looked into the Saxon and XqueryBuilder code that there was some difference.

But I suspect the Camel version upgrade from 2.17 to 2.21 because by debugging XqueryBuilder, the xmlns namespace of my route is not taken into account in Camel 2.17 whereas in 2.21 it appears in the variable: namespacePrefixes of XqueryBuilder.

I continue my research.

Comment: @Roy9590 
Have you found some solution for the problem. With Camel 2.22.0 and Saxon-HE-9.8.0-12.jar I got the same error:

org.apache.camel.RuntimeExpressionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Misdeclaration of xmlns namespace at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:155) ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1] at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:120) ~[camel-saxon-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1] at org.apache.camel.processor.TransformProcessor.process(TransformProcessor.java:50) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]